# Curvature of flat bundle vanishes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-bundles

In the book differential geometry of complex vector bundles by Kobayashi, the book is free online, https://www.mathsoc.jp/assets/pdf/publications/pubmsj/Vol15.pdf. The screenshot of the page 5 is below.

In the proof of the equivalence between flatness of a vector bundle and the vanish of curvature, how is the red equal sign in the screenshot achieved? To me it seems like he is using some form of torsion free condition of the connection, i.e. $da+\omega' a$=0 . But the author did not mention torsion in this section. How did the author get the equation?

Another question I have is, does integrability of the differential equation imply the solvability of it? I don't have much knowledge on it so any reference about this would also be helpful.

[image]

Comment: This is a repeated question and was answered in mathoverflow
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364793/integrability-condition-for-flat-connections

Comment: Just a side comment. Torsion in general is defined only for the tangent bundle. This equation came from (1.2.2).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the equation above the one above the one where you underlined, $da=-\omega’ a$. You replace $da$ in the left hand of the equality you underlined and you will get the right hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the equation right above the equality I underlined is what we want to solve right? For example, if we want to solve $f(x)=0$, we want to solve firstly the integrability condition $d(f(x))=0$, but can we use $f(x)=0$ as a condition to solve $df(x)=0$ ?

Comment: You assume for the integrability condition, that you have a solution $a$ which then has to satisfy said condition. So you can use what you know to be true for a solution from the equation below 1.2.2

Comment: Yes, as explained by Jfischer, the part after the conversely is about the the possibility of finding a parallel section. That would mean existence of the $a$ satisfying equation 1.2.2 or its equivalent form just after. But then this would imply the final equation. Throughout, you can indeed thus use the equation above the one in red.